# Manually categorize vs Decision Tree categorize in Classification

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, gradient-descent, kaggle

encountering a problem when doing a classification problem in Kaggle competition.
If I am trying to categorize numeric variables or categorical variables into other categories manually(from plotting and observing from their distributions), and also find out Decision Tree Tree Graph seems not doing as good in categorizing, should I manually categorize them, to have a better classification accuracy result?

Basically, the question is, can Decision Tree and Random Forest and GradienBoost DT do such a job good enough so that my manual re-categorization has no merit and there is no need to manually categorize and feature engineer in this way?

Comment: also, i am thinking of checking the tree graph and accuracy again after doing my manual categorization. If it has better results, i will implement such feature engineering

Comment: I have just read a master's thesis where the result was significantly improved by the fact that the author of the master's thesis did not only create manual categories, but the categories were vectors with three values. This is something that no standard algorithm can do for you.